# Can Mizzium Meddler steal the effect of a Renown ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Basically, I am thinking of a situation: say [Outland Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Outland%20Colossus) attacks and deals damage to a player. Before the Renown ability resolves, can I activate [Mizzium Meddler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mizzium%20Meddler) to steal the six +1/+1 counters? Is Renown an ability that Mizzium Meddler can steal? I am not sure how Renown works on the stack, if at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mizzium Meddler cannot 'steal' the Renown of the Colossus.

This is because Renown is not a targeted ability, it just effects the creature it is on.

> **702.111a** Renown is a triggered ability. “Renown N” means “When this creature deals combat damage to a player, if it isn’t renowned, put N +1/+1 counters on it and it becomes renowned.”

As you can see there is no mention of targeting anywhere in the rules, thus the Meddler cannot redirect it. Note that the Meddler can still target the ability, it will just do nothing since there are no targets to change.

> If Mizzium Meddler’s triggered ability targets a spell or ability with no targets, nothing happens.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, would've been cool to do it but meh thanks for the swift answer :)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. Renown is a triggered ability:

> 702.111a **Renown is a triggered ability**. “Renown N” means “When this creature deals combat damage to a player, if it isn’t renowned, put N +1/+1 counters on it and it becomes renowned.”

But it is not targeted, since to be considered one it should have the word "target" in it:

> 114.1d A triggered ability is targeted if it identifies something it will affect by using **the phrase “target [something],”** where the “something” is a phrase that describes an object, player, or zone. The target(s) are chosen as the ability is put on the stack; see rule 603.3d.

Therefore you can target triggered Renown ability, but nothing will happen since you won't be able to change the target as Renown doesn't have one.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Only three things target:

1. Spells and abilities on the stack that have the word "target" in their text.
2. Spells and abilities on the stack that have a keyword ability that has the word "target" in their text.
3. Auras on the stack (since the rules for them uses the word "target").

"Renown" is keyword ability, but it doesn't have the word "target" in its text:

> 702.111a Renown is a triggered ability. “Renown N” means “When this creature deals combat damage to a player, if it isn’t renowned, put N +1/+1 counters on it and it becomes renowned.”

Mizzium Meddler can't affect the ability since it has no target to change.